# Criteria for remove response variables in random forest model

Tags: r, random-forest

I've like to find a criteria for response variables selection based on Mean Decrease Gini and Mean Decrease Accuracy. In my original dataset I have 49 response variables and my machine spend a lot of time (days) for extract that in a raster object. Then, I search for any statistical criteria approach for remove response variables with low importance in random forest (RF) model. My problem with a generic example:

```
#Packages
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)

#Classical iris data set
data(iris)
Rep<-seq(1,length(iris[,1]))
all_iris<-cbind(Rep,iris)


#Tranning RF model
dg_o_cal<-all_iris %>% sample_n(150*0.8)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length 
+ Petal.Width, data=dg_o_cal, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)

#Plot  Mean Decrease Gini and Mean Decrease Accuracy 
varImpPlot(iris.rf)
```

[image: Var importance plot]

And now, I've like to apply any statistical criteria, for example, that calculate 6.5 value for Mean Decrease Gini and Mean Decrease Accuracy. With this, a will remove Septal.Width of my data set with low importance. And my final model was:

```
#Final RF
iris.rf2 <- randomForest(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Length 
+ Petal.Width, data=dg_o_cal, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)
iris.rf2 
iris.rf

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Species ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Length +      Petal.Width, data = dg_o_cal, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 1

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 5%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         36          0         0  0.00000000
versicolor      0         41         3  0.06818182
virginica       0          3        37  0.07500000

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width +      Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = dg_o_cal, importance = TRUE,      proximity = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 5%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         36          0         0  0.00000000
versicolor      0         41         3  0.06818182
virginica       0          3        37  0.07500000
```

With this, I removed the low importance variables and OOB estimate of error rate continuous the same. Then, my question is, there any kind of statistical criteria approach for my situation?

Comment: `I removed the low importance variables` ... you _don't_ /should not be doing this.  This isn't how random forests works.  The way forests are built already means that weak predictors won't have much impact on the final model.

Comment: Read here: https://explained.ai/rf-importance/index.html. tldr DON'T trust those importances, it's better to perform variable permutation and control how the performance changes. The basic idea is that a variable is important if the performance is worse when it's values are permuted before the model train.